Failed Ubuntu and Windows dual boot. How do I undo my dual boot?
I have attempted to install Windows along side of my Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Desktop. Windows works fine, however I could not boot into Ubuntu but can boot into Windows.
I have given up on dual boot, so how do I wipe everything and start fresh with Ubuntu ONLY. NOT DUAL BOOT?
Is there any risk of bricking my hard drive if I just treat my computer like Windows and attempt to wipe and install Ubuntu?
Given that I have a partition for Windows and partition for Ubuntu, are there any extra steps in wiping and maintaining a single partition with Ubuntu?
My hardware = b450 tomahawk max, R5 3600, RX580 8GB. I was using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Desktop and yes I have internet available.


It's usually far easier to start with windows, and then install Ubuntu (or any other OS, windows doesn't cater/expect dual booting). You've given no clues as to what Ubuntu product/release you're using, so we cannot know what installer you'll be using (ubiquity, subiquity, ubuntu-desktop-installer are installers used by Ubuntu; selected by product/release you download!)  Don't do a destructive install is what I'll suggest with your chosen Ubuntu product/release (ubiquity and calamares installers would be my choice as easiest)

I have edited the question @guiverc

Providing a release would have been useful; eg. Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Desktop as installer versions tend to vary on release (though the snap installers can update if internet is available & user allows it, but you don't mention you doing that anyway or whether internet is available)

Just use the usb live ubuntu to mount to partition with old Ubuntu, backup your data from the partition into another usb. Then do a fresh install of ubuntu in advanced mode to wipe the drive containing the dual boot.
FYI, if you want to dual boot, just back everything up. Install windows first to deal with any BIOS issues. Then install Ubuntu on top.
